# Play a camera from one Raspberry Pi to another using Python 3 via WIFI

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I want to play a camera from One Raspberry Pi 3 to another Raspberry Pi 3 using the Python language via WIFI. But I have an error that I cannot understand and cannot not solve.

I have already tried to solve this error but it comes again and I do not understand the point of the error.

```
import cv2
import sys

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(r'fifo')
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

while True:
# Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
if ret == False:
    pass

cv2.imshow('image',frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

When everything is done, release the capture:

```
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my Python 3 code for the camera. And this is an error come in my code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testMkFifo.py", line 14, in <module>
  cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) /home/pi/packaging/opencv- 
python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion 
failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation - your code cannot run as shown. Please show the code that puts data into the fifo from the other side.

Comment: Hi...There is one .sh file have to develop a code as mentioned below,    #!/bin/bash

if [ -p fifo264 ]
then
        rm fifo264
fi
mkfifo fifo264
nc -l -v -p 8000 > fifo264        /.....Here fifo264 file will create and as above python code will give me the output by this file at another raspberry pi location. Here some confusion but this is my answer. I hope you will understand.